# How to Avoid Nested Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I've read that nested queries can potentially slow down the overall query, and was wanting to know a way to avoid this in my code.
I am basically wanting to sum up the total value of all orders for each customer (Customer here is indicated by CUSTOMER_EMAIL).
I need to select some fields which will be used in the CASE statement (D365_ID and STORE_NAME) which will be used to insert a new column and determine the currency but when I group the result, I don't want to show these fields (D365_ID and STORE_NAME) anymore.

My original code was:

```
select CUSTOMER_EMAIL, D365_ID, STORE_NAME,
    sum(line_price) VALUE_Total,
    count(distinct order_id) AS Orders_Total, 
    CASE 
        WHEN D365_ID = 'NORD' THEN 'EURO'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'US' THEN 'USD'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'UK' THEN 'GBP'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'LMG' THEN 'EURO'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'SWE' THEN 'SEK'     
        WHEN D365_ID = 'Unknown' THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'DE%' THEN 'EURO'
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'SE EUR%' THEN 'EURO'
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'SE SEK%' THEN 'SEK'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
            END
        ELSE 'Unknown'
      END CURRENCY
      from "CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS"
group by customer_email, D365_ID, CURRENCY, STORE_NAME
```

However, I'm unable to drop D365_ID and STORE_NAME and was forced to put it in the group by clause.

I had to change my code and create a nested query in order to not have these fields in the final result.

Nested query:

```
select CUSTOMER_EMAIL, CURRENCY,
    sum(line_price) VALUE_Total,
    count(distinct order_id) AS Orders_Total,
from 
(SELECT CUSTOMER_EMAIL, D365_ID, STORE_NAME, line_price, order_date, order_id,
      CASE 
        WHEN D365_ID = 'NORD' THEN 'EURO'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'US' THEN 'USD'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'UK' THEN 'GBP'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'LMG' THEN 'EURO'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'SWE' THEN 'SEK'     
        WHEN D365_ID = 'Unknown' THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'DE%' THEN 'EURO'
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'SE EUR%' THEN 'EURO'
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'SE SEK%' THEN 'SEK'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
            END
        ELSE 'Unknown'
      END CURRENCY
    from "CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS")
group by customer_email, CURRENCY
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREAT TABLE CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS`

Comment: Can't a customer buy from more than one store?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the columns in the group by either the alias or the column order

```
select CUSTOMER_EMAIL, 
    CASE 
        WHEN D365_ID = 'NORD' THEN 'EURO'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'US' THEN 'USD'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'UK' THEN 'GBP'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'LMG' THEN 'EURO'
        WHEN D365_ID = 'SWE' THEN 'SEK'     
        WHEN D365_ID = 'Unknown' THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'DE%' THEN 'EURO'
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'SE EUR%' THEN 'EURO'
                WHEN STORE_NAME LIKE 'SE SEK%' THEN 'SEK'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
            END
        ELSE 'Unknown'
      END CURRENCY
    sum(line_price) VALUE_Total,
    count(distinct order_id) AS Orders_Total, 
    
      from "CUSTOMER_TRANSACTIONS"
group by CUSTOMER_EMAIL, CURRENCY
--OR group by CUSTOMER_EMAIL, 2
```